# 'AND' vs 'and ' in python multi condition if statement

Tags: python

I have the following python statement:

```
 if((criteria is not None) AND (2 <= criteria <= 5)):
```

I am using pycharm3 , which suggests that there is a a syntax error here. when I hover over the line it says: a colon is required.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python uses `and`, not `AND`; you don't need nearly as many parentheses either (as `and` has very low [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)):

```
if criteria is not None and 2 <= criteria <= 5:
```

When you spell it `AND`, it is seen as a variable name instead, making the expression invalid.

You can simplify the test to:

```
if criteria and 2 <= criteria <= 5:
```

as `None` is false anyway and `0` would not fit in the range.

In Python 2, `None` can be compared to numbers directly (is always smaller) and `if 2 <= criteria <= 5:` would do, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit and compatible with Python 3.

Demo:

```
>>> for criteria in (None, 0, 3, 5, 10):
...     if criteria and 2 <= criteria <= 5:
...         print(criteria, 'is valid')
...     else:
...         print(criteria, 'does not match')
... 
None does not match
0 does not match
3 is valid
5 is valid
10 does not match
```

Comment: Thanks I'm coming from php where 'and' , 'AND' are the same. Much appreciated - Bill

Comment: Martijn, regarding the "off topic" - I don't know if this helps but I changed the title hoping to make this more relevant to a broader audience. regards, - Bill

Comment: @user61629: It *is* a basic syntax 'typo' in that the [reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) would have told you `AND` isn't supported. :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as `AND`, it should be `and`:

```
if((criteria is not None) and (2 <= criteria <= 5)):
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters I had no idea you DIDN'T have to test for `None` in Python2. Why would those be orderable?!

Comment: @AdamSmith: Because Python 2 tries to make everything orderable, so sorting a homogenous list works. `None` sorts before numbers, which sort before everything else, which are sorted on type *name*. Unless explicit ordering is supported, of course.

Comment: Thanks guys , sorry about such a basic question, I'm new to python and missed and vs AND

Comment: @user61629, No problem, Glad we could help.